comparing convergence rates of expressions equal to $\zeta(s)$.
I am studying this representation of the Riemann zeta function for real $s>1$:
$$\zeta(s)=I(s)-F(s). $$
or equivalently:
$$\zeta(s)=2\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \int_{J=(0,n^{-s/2})} e^{\frac{s^2\log^2({n})}{4\log t}}~dt -\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \int_{U=(0,1)} e^{\frac{s^2\log^2({n})}{4\log t}}~dt \tag{custom representation}$$
Here you can see this desmos plot of the function.
I compared the rates of convergence for the classical zeta representation to the Borwein method (fastest known) and my "custom representation" for $\zeta(s)$ was better than the classical but not as good as the Borwein method.


Does the convergence rate increase if the function $$\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \int_{U=(0,1)} e^{\frac{s^2\log^2({n})}{4\log t}}~dt$$ is simplified to $$s\sum_{n\in \Bbb N} \log n~K_1(s\log n)$$ where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind?


Your desmos link doesn't seem to work. Your plot seems to illustrate the classical Dirichlet series converges faster than your custom representation or what you call the "Fastest converger". In fact the latter two don't even seem to be converging. Or maybe you need to clarify your definition of error?

Perhaps you're confusing the Riemann zeta function
$$\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_n \frac{1}{n^s},\quad\Re(s)>1$$
with the Dirichlet eta function $$\eta(s)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right), \zeta (s)=\sum\limits_n \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s},\quad\Re(s)>0$$
and comparing series for $\eta(s)$ with $\zeta(s)$ in two of the evaluations in your plot?

How are you defining convergence rate?

@DanielDonnelly # of new accurate decimal places added per term
